# How would I return full output from function in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, xml, codeigniter

I need to output all books from all shelfs. This code bellow only outputs last shelf of books. Any help would be helpful.

### My Controller:

```
function index()
{
  $data['books'] = $this->_books();
  $this->load->view('books_view', $data);
}

function _books() {
  $xml = simplexml_load_file('books.xml');
  foreach ($xml->shelfs as $shelf)
  {
    $result = '<optgroup label="'.$shelf['id'].'">';
    foreach ($shelf->books as $book)
    {
      $result .= '<option value="'.$book->title.'">'.$book->title.'</option>';
    }
    $result .= '</optgroup>';
  }
  return $result;
}
```

### My View:

```
echo form_open('books#');
echo '<select name="books[]" multiple="multiple" onClick="this.form.submit()">';
echo $options;
echo '</select></form>';
```

### My Output:

only last shelf which is "Z".

### My XML Data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<library>

<shelfs id="A">
  <strip>
    <title>Book Title #1 for A</title>
    <author>Author Name #1 for A</author>
  </strip>
  <strip>
    <title>Book Title #2 for A</title>
    <author>Author Name #2 for A</author>
  </strip>
</comics>

...

<shelfs id="Z">
  <strip>
    <title>Book Title #1 for Z</title>
    <author>Author Name #1 for Z</author>
  </strip>
  <strip>
    <title>Book Title #2 for Z</title>
    <author>Author Name #2 for Z</author>
  </strip>
</comics>

</library>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are overwriting `$result` it should be `.=` and defined before `foreach` begins

```
function _books() {
  $xml = simplexml_load_file('books.xml');
  $result='';
  foreach ($xml->shelfs as $shelf)
  {
    $result.= '<optgroup label="'.$shelf['id'].'">';
    foreach ($shelf->books as $book)
    {
      $result .= '<option value="'.$book->title.'">'.$book->title.'</option>';
    }
    $result .= '</optgroup>';
  }
  return $result;
}
```

Comment: Oh my God. Thanks mate. I have been hammering for an hour or so now, without any luck LOL This worked great for me. I can believe its so simple wow. Thank you so much.

Comment: @EMC you should **definitely** accept this answer! Please give credit where it is due and let everyone else know that this is resolved, read the FAQ and guidelines blah blah blah...

Comment: I did guys :) I can't click on the arrows any more. I see green arrow, this means accepted.

Comment: @EMC: This is fine now and accepted. No need to do anything. Answer is already accepted by you. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here:

```
$result = '<optgroup label="'.$shelf['id'].'">';
```

You are resetting the `$result` variable at the beginning of each loop.

Yes what @Shakti Singh said!

Comment: Thanks Madmartigan, I understand now :)